# Error with typedef and function declaration

Tags: c++, c, function, declaration

I don't understand why I it tells I have an invalid function declaration, when I'm just declaring a variable. Also, I don't get why my typedef did not work.

```
Username@Server 388> g++ -Wall -pthread testHashT.cpp -o testHashT
memHashT.h:22: error: invalid function declaration
memHashT.h: In function âvoid memAccessUpdate(void*, unsigned int, pthread_t, bool)â:
memHashT.h:114: error: cannot convert âmList*â to âlinkedMlist*â in assignment
memHashT.h:119: error: cannot convert âlinkedMlist*â to âmList*â in assignment
memHashT.h:128: error: âcountWSâ was not declared in this scope
memHashT.h:133: error: âcountRAâ was not declared in this scope
```

```
Username@Server 389> cat memHashT.h
//Basic hash table for memory addresses, recommended size for program running is table indexed by a prime ~81281


/************************************************************
* Structure of table:
* Hash table indexed by memory address
* at each entry a vector made of arrays with size 2 of void pointers
* each vector entry will have the unique memory address and a pointer to a vector
* the vector it points to will contain a list of all threads that accessed that location
*
* Overall:(currently being changed to HT=>LL=>LL
* Hash Table => Vector => Vector Containing threads that accessed a given memory location
*************************************************************/

#include <pthread.h>//same as bellow
#include <stdlib.h>//watch out in case actual function contains this
//using namespace std;

//Global var
unsigned int tableSize; //note this is best if it is a prime number
unsigned long long countWA;
unsigned long long countRA:
unsigned long long countWS;
unsigned long long countRS;
//Linked Lists (thread, then mem)
//added all information in T_list to the M list, can be deleted
/*struct linkedT_list {
    int threadID;
    struct linkedT_list * nextT;
};
typedef struct linkedT_list tList;
tList * currT, * headT;*/


//For memory addresses
struct linkedM_list {
    void * memAddr;

    //Details
        bool shared;
        pthread_t  prevThread;
        unsigned long long rCounter;
        unsigned long long wCounter;
    //End Details
    struct linkedMlist * nextM;
};
typedef struct linkedM_list mList;
//mList * currM, * headM;

mList ** hashTable;

//computes the index of the hash table
        //made its own function in case future implementation need to change how indexing is set up
unsigned int getHTIndex (void * arg){
    return (unsigned int) ((unsigned long long)arg%tableSize);
}
//returns pointer to mList containing information
        //NOT CORRECTLY IMPLEMENTED YET, NEED TO FIND RIGHT MEM ADDRESS, NOT JUST TOP MEM
mList * getHTElement(void * arg){
    mList * tempM;
    //tList * tempT = NULL;
    unsigned int index = getHTIndex(arg);
    tempM = hashTable[index];
    //tempT = tempM->threadList;
    return tempM;
}
//remove a element

void removeHTElement(void * memArg){
    //note no garbage collection yet
    ;
}

//returns the number of threads to access a memery location
int tLength(void * arg){
    return -1;
}
//Create the hash table
int createHashTable(unsigned int num) {
    tableSize =  num;
    hashTable = (mList **) malloc(sizeof(mList) * tableSize);
   if (hashTable == NULL)
   {
        return 0;
        //printf("Error: Memory could not be allocated");
   }
   else {
        unsigned int i;

        for(i=0;i<tableSize;i++)
        {
            hashTable[i]=NULL;
        }
   }
    return 1;
}

void destroyHashTable(){
    free(hashTable);
}

//adds a element to the hash table
void memAccessUpdate(void * memArg, unsigned int thread, pthread_t thread_id,  bool writeAccess){
    mList * headM = getHTElement(memArg);
    mList * currM;
    if (headM == NULL)
    {//then create and new mList
        currM = (mList *)malloc(sizeof(mList));
        //initialize values
        currM->shared = false;
        currM->prevThread = thread_id;
        currM->rCounter = 0;
        currM->wCounter = 0;
        currM->nextM = hashTable[getHTIndex(memArg)];
        hashTable[getHTIndex(memArg)] = currM;
    }
    else {//change details in linked list and global var
        //headM->nextM = (mList *)malloc(sizeof(mList));
        currM = headM->nextM;
        if (thread_id != currM->prevThread){
            currM->shared = true;
            currM->prevThread = thread_id;
        }
        if(writeAccess)
        {
            countWA++;
            if(currM->shared){
                countWS++;
            }
            currM->wCounter++;
        }
        else{//mem read
            countRA++;
            if(currM->shared){
                countRS++;
            }
            currM->rCounter++;
        }
    }
    //if (stuff) //possibly don't need
    //else
   // head = hashTable[index]; //note may be null
   // curr = (mList *)malloc(sizeof(mList));
   // curr->
}
```

I'm very confused as to why I'm getting those errors. Any help is appreciated. (I know its not good practice to declare functions in a header, but for now I'm just looking to correct my syntax).

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, but (assuming this is from the MacOS X Terminal) if you set **Terminal->Preferences->Settings->Advanced->Character encoding** to **Unocode (UTF-8)**, the output from the compiler will be more readable, as the `â` will be printed as a quote character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! It took me a while, what with my eyesight...Look carefully at the last character of line 22 :-)

Also, decide whether you want to call it `linkedMlist` or `linkedM_list`. (That one wasn't so hard on the eyes.)

Comment: Although why it looks like a function declaration to the compiler, I don't know!

Comment: @Charles: must be a `C++` thing :)

Answer (score 2):

`struct linkedMlist` is not defined or declared, as far as I can see

```
struct linkedM_list {
    void * memAddr;

    //Details
        bool shared;
        pthread_t  prevThread;
        unsigned long long rCounter;
        unsigned long long wCounter;
    //End Details
    struct linkedMlist * nextM;                // <===== HERE
};
```